# Calculating Gear Ratio in PHP using loop array

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm trying to design a car's gear ratio calculator that takes certain vehicle's dimensions as input. One way to calculate them is trough using geometric progression method. Below are the codes I'm trying to run:

```
<?

$alowgearf = 14.37;
$ahigear = 3.293;
$noOfGear = 5;
$loopLimit = $noOfGear - 2;

$gears = array(0 => "$alowgearf", "$noOfGear - 1" => "$ahigear");

$nlnh = $alowgearf/$ahigear;
$cgp = pow($nlnh, 1/($noOfGear - 1));



for ( $n = 1; $n <= $loopLimit ; $n++ ) {
$m = $n - 1;
$gear = $gears[$m]/$cgp;
$gears[$n] = $gear;
}





print_r($gears);

?>
```

The formula for the GPM method of calculating gear ratio is as follows :

N[i+1] = N[i]/Cgp,

where N is gear ratio, i is the gear number and Cgp is the geometric progression constant.

By supplying the formula with the lowest and highest gear ratio and the desired number of gears, we can calculate the rest of the gear ratios.

The problem is, the codes above outputs nothing. I've been trying to fix the code but I can't detect any problem with them. I've been toying with other loop function such as do-while but the results are the same. What's the problem? What I've been doing wrong?

Comment: code work fine here http://ideone.com/VTbiJO

Comment: I can run it without any problems.

Comment: The example works. Your issue is probably because you're using a short php tag. what happens when you change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: Result is `Array
(
    [0] => 14.37
    [4] => 3.293
    [1] => 9.9423834528791
    [2] => 6.8789832097484
    [3] => 4.7594633846371
)
` - just for info.

Comment: Your `$gears` array has a key named `"$noOfGear - 1"`. This is literally the string `5 - 1` as a key name which I'm assuming isn't what you want. You likely want to remove the quotes and wrap in parenthesis for it to evaluate the expression and return 4.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn that must be some later edit, I copied it and in my copy there is `4` in place of this atrocity.

Comment: @MightyPork Likely so. But it is still an error and would definitely cause the code to not work as expected.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn yeah I edited it after remembering I've tinkered the with the originals variables and codes after a hell lot of frustrations. Thanks for the advice btw